# QT Installation Missing compiler

Tags: installation, qt, offline

I have used Linux in the past but not for a long time and so I am a bit rusty so apologise if I am asking something obvious or in the wrong stackexchange site.

There are a few things with regards to how I have to use Ubuntu that are likely important:

1. I have to use it virtually, so it is installed in a Virtualbox
2. I do not have access to an internet connection due to company policy. Software is downloaded for me though so i can get hold of it as long as it is available as offline installers

So, I have used the desktop version of Ubuntu 12.4 LTS x64 and an offline installer of QT.

When i try to install QT it first complains about a missing C++ compiler: "You need a c++ compiler. Please install it using the System Management tools"

I have, as far as I was aware, GCC installed as part of the Ubuntu install but maybe this is something else I need.

If I ignore all that it seems to install but only has the Harmattan target available. Leading me to think I am missing some software.

Any ideas what i need and how to get these as offline installations?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate about downloading offline installers. Do you have a proxy? Are you able to download a file from http:// page?

Comment: I cannot download anything like that. Not from apt-get, not from http unfortunatley. It is all blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `g++` package. Install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

If you are going to install it by downloading this package for offline installation, there is a bunch of dependencies, and you need to download and install all of those as well.

[These](http://snipt.org/ujQe7) are dependencies for `libqt4-dev` package on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: I ran that command and it said that I do have the most recent versions of all the software so I guess thats a default install. Must be something else that I need to do for QT. But all that said, if it happened that I need software that isn't installed and given I am limited to offline. Is it possible to create a list of dependencies that an install needs and is there a source for downloading and installing these?

Comment: g++ is not installed by default.

Comment: apt-rdepends is the package that can list all dependencies recursively for a given package. I've updated my answer with dependency list for libqt4-dev.

Comment: I am using Qt5.1.1 on Wubi 32bit. However, `sudo apt-get install g++` or `sudo apt-get install build-essential` doesn't work. I tried: sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ and it works.